# Access classifier as property during maven build

Tags: java, maven, jar, build

I have a pom.xml with several classifier specified as follows:

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <classifier>first</classifier>
       </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>jar-1</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>jar</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <classifier>jar1</classifier>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>jar2</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>jar</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <classifier>jar2</classifier>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

In a single package a different jar is compiled for every classifier.
For every classifier I want to specify a different value for the same property which I'm trying to do with a separate profile (one for each classifier).

```
<profile>
        <id>first</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>classifier</name>
                <value>first</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <someProperty>Value for this classifier</someProperty>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

The problem here is that I don't know how to access the value of the classifier (I imagine it as property) in order to activate the profile.